# Your bad intonation is more likely to make your informal English sound unnatural than grammar {is / will / would}?

Tags: subjunctives

> Your bad intonation is more likely to make your informal English sound unnatural than
>
> grammar
>
> grammar will/would/is

which is correct?

Answer (score 2):

> Your bad intonation is more likely to make your informal English sound unnatural than **bad** grammar is.

Putting an extra bad in there to make the sentence less ambiguous is probably a good idea, although it can be omitted.

I think is works here, because of the present tense of

> is more likely

It makes more sense that the second half of the sentence is in the present tense as well.

> bad intonation **is** more likely to make your...
>   bad grammar **is** more likely to make your...

Although I would say that in casual conversation they could probably all be used and nobody would really notice.

Comment: Thank you. I was also thinking of rephrasing the whole sentence into a simpler one. How about this?: Your informal English is more likely to come off as unnatural by your bad intonation than by bad grammar.

Comment: That would work well also. Nice use of the superlative.